# Openpyxl Excel cell value is non existent

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Hy all

I'm writing a script to check if there are empty values in my excel columns. If there is an empty value i want the corresponding row to that empty cell copied to a new worksheet for easy analysis.

This is the code:

```
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter



def searchForBlanks(wb, ws, header):
    ws2 = wb.create_sheet(header + " irregularities")


    #copying over the header 
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
        ws2.append((cell.value for cell in row))

    #Getting the header coordinates to check
    for col in ws.columns:
        column = get_column_letter(col[0].column)
        for cell in col:
            if str(cell.value) == str(header):
                char = column
                print(char)

                #checking if the dedicated column contains a irregularity and than copying the whole row
                for row in ws:
                    value = ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value
                    coll = ws[char + str(row[0].row)]


                    print(str(coll) + '  ' + str(value))

                    if ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == 0 or ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == None or ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == False:
                        ws2.append((cell.value for cell in row))
```

My input that i give is **wb= workbook path, ws = worksheet, header = header column title i want to check**

If i run it i get the following example output:

```
K
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K1>  City
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K2>  None
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K3>  None
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K4>
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K5>
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K6>
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K7>
<Cell 'LoadFile'.K8>
```

If i check the new excel sheet that was created i get only the first 2 rows from the 'None' values. From K4 to K8 are not copied. How do i make sure i copy these rows aswell?

So for some reason my criteria are not broad enough to copy these non-existent values.

Can somebody give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was constantly validating the output in my console that i did not validate them in Excel.

I turns out there was a cell value in excel. It was just a space ' ' that was the answer and i had to add it to my criteria and now it works.

```
if ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == 0 or ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == None or ws[char + str(row[0].row)].value == " ":
```